# how to move and remove files in WinJS

Tags: javascript, file, visual-studio-2012, winjs

I build a metro application in WinJS which creates an image in a temporary folder in my hard drive (C:\users\temp...)

but I want to move my pictures to another directory, how do I do that??
thanks in advance for the support

also I want to know how to delete them by using WinJS or Javascript

thanks for the support

---

Code

```
function imageCapture() {
        //Invoke the camera capture UI for snapping a photo
        var captureUI = new _capture.CameraCaptureUI();
        captureUI.photoSettings.format = _capture.CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.jpeg;  
        captureUI.captureFileAsync(_capture.CameraCaptureUIMode.photo)
            .then(function (capturedItem) {
                if (capturedItem) {

                    console.log("image path: " + capturedItem.path);

                    //Creates the photo
                    var photoBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(capturedItem, { oneTimeOnly: true });
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Could you show the code where you've gotten stuck? You can't arbitrarily access folders in WinRT without specific application permissions requested in the Manifest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx

Comment: I updated the code with the image creation, this stores the picture in--- C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Packages\9e8dbb07-5b53-4c61-b7c3-3837d07b6210_jxw2p3as84a1r\TempState\imagenxxxx.jpg, I don't have enabled yet Documents/Music/Video library folder on manifest but it still working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can treat your image as Storagefile. Using Storagefile you can move to another folder using [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.moveasync.aspx) & [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh738483.aspx)

If you want delete use like

`storageFile.deleteAsync().done( /* Your success and error handlers */ );`

Here you have to remember  **WiredPrairie** comment that *You can't access folders without specific application permissions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx#Accessing_additional_locations)*.

AFAIK it will work